# What is in this code? i am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Tags: php

i am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'` I cannot figure out whats wrong with this code. Kindly help

my code here

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_CHANGEID']) == TRUE) {
session_unset();
session_regenerate_id();
}
require("config.php");
?>

<?php echo $config_sitename; ?>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="menu">
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a> -

<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php">View Basket/Checkout</a></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="bar">
<?php
require("bar.php");

echo "<hr />";

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE)
{
echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a href="&quot; . $config_basedir. &quot;logout.php>"logout</a>]";
}
else
{
echo "<a href="&quot;. $config_basedir . &quot;login.php">Login</a>";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<a href="&quot;. $config_basedir . &quot;login.php">Login</a>";
```

replace with:

```
echo "<a href='".$config_basedir."login.php'>Login</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
echo "<a href="&quot;. $config_basedir
```

Fix the quote

```
echo "<a href=&quot;". $config_basedir
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this, Reason for `&quot;` issue.

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE)
    {
    echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a href='" . $config_basedir."'logout.php>logout</a>]";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<a href='". $config_basedir ."'login.php>Login</a>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed code. I would recommend to use IDE with syntax highlighting. I.e. PhpStorm.

```
<?php echo $config_sitename; ?>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a> -

        <a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php">View Basket/Checkout</a></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="bar">
<?php
require("bar.php");

echo "<hr />";

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE)
{
    echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a href=\"&quot;" . $config_basedir. "&quot;logout.php>\"logout</a>]";
}
else
{
    echo "<a href=\"&quot; ". $config_basedir . "&quot;login.php\">Login</a>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Do not include double quotes inside double quotes or single quotes inside single quotes
but include double into single and inverse.

```
In this line `echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a href="&quot; . $config_basedir. &quot;logout.php>"logout</a>]";

`
Just replace "&quot; with '&quot;
and replace "logout with 'logout

and in this line `echo "<a href="&quot;. $config_basedir . &quot;login.php">Login</a>";
`

Just replace "&quot; with '&quot;
and replace login.php" with login.php'
```